# Connecting PostgreSQL to an existing GIS Geodatabase

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am currently using PostgreSQL 10 along with PGAdmin 4 and am curious if it is possible to connect to an existing GIS Geodatabase through the PGAdmin console? I would like to query /edit data that exists within a Geodatabase and my current workflow is to export the data and import it into a PostgreSQL database. Connecting straight into the geodatabase would streamline my workflow.

Comment: Sure you can, but pgAdmin doesn't have special support for visualizing PostGIS data. You could try a specialized tool like QGIS.

Comment: I currently use ArcMap for my processing and visualization. I would like to use postgres to access a geodatabase used by ArcMap. I would only utilize pgAdmin to query the data.

Comment: Wishful thinking. pgAdmin cannot do that. I don't know if there is a tool that can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use pgAdmin4 for visualizing GIS data.

Check the pgAdmin4 docs for more details: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/editgrid.html#the-data-grid

[image]